# Why does this throw exception

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

The test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestStringWithValidAndInvalid()
{
    MockRepository mocks = new MockRepository();
    ICentipedeCore mockCore = mocks.DynamicMock<ICentipedeCore>();
    IPythonEngine pythonEngine = mocks.StrictMock<IPythonEngine>();
    IPythonByteCode mockPythonByteCode = mocks.Stub<IPythonByteCode>();

    mockCore.Stub(c => c.PythonEngine)
            .Return(pythonEngine);

    pythonEngine.Expect(e => e.Compile(Arg<String>.Is.Equal("\"String\""),
                                       Arg<PythonByteCode.SourceCodeType>.Is.Anything))
                .Return(mockPythonByteCode);

    pythonEngine.Expect(e => e.Evaluate(Arg<IPythonByteCode>.Is.Equal(mockPythonByteCode),
                                        Arg<PythonScope>.Is.Anything))
                .Return(3);

    pythonEngine.Expect(e => e.Compile(Arg<String>.Is.Equal("this is invalid python"),
                                       Arg<PythonByteCode.SourceCodeType>.Is.Anything))
                .Throw(new PythonParseException(mocks.Stub<Exception>()));


    ActionWrapper testAction = new ActionWrapper(mockCore);

    var original = @"{1+2} with {invalid python}";
    var expected = "3 with {invalid python}";
    var result = testAction.ParseStringForVariable(original); // ActionTest.cs: line 267

    mocks.VerifyAll();
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
}
```

The method under test (exposed by a wrapper):

```
protected String ParseStringForVariable([NotNull] String str)
{
    IPythonEngine pythonEngine = GetCurrentCore().PythonEngine;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] != '{')
        {
            continue;
        }

        int opening = i;
        foreach (var expression in from closing in str.IndexesWhere('}'.Equals)
                                   where closing > opening
                                   select new
                                          {
                                              Template = str.Substring(opening, closing - opening + 1),
                                              Code = str.Substring(opening + 1, closing - opening - 1)
                                          })
        {
            IPythonByteCode compiled;
            try
            {
                compiled = pythonEngine.Compile(expression.Code, PythonByteCode.SourceCodeType.Expression);
            }
            catch (PythonParseException)
            {
                // not valid python, try next expression
                continue;
            }
            dynamic r = pythonEngine.Evaluate(compiled);
            String result = r.ToString(); //  Action.cs: line 217, wrapped at  ActionTest.cs: line 96
            str = str.Replace(expression.Template, result);
            break;
        }
    }

    return str;
}
```

The Exception:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

The exception is thrown on the line after `dynamic r = pythonEngine.Evaluate(compiled);` with `r` being null. but I don't know why - `compiled` has the same value as mockPythonByteCode, pythonEngine is the mock created in the test, and the identical call works in a different method.  The only difference here, is that `pythonEngine.Compile` has two Expectations, on different inputs, with different results.

The problem is, I've got `TestStringWithValidCode()` and `TestStringWithInvalidCode()`, both working fine, which I merged to form `TestStringWithValidAndInvalid()`, so each half **should** work.

Comment: Are we meant to guess where the exception is being throw?

Comment: At what point in the exception thrown? You can set a breakpoint at the beginning of your test and instead of selecting "Run Test" you can select "Debug Test" which will let you step through the code. This will likely also give you your answer as you'll see the null reference.

Comment: Damn, knew I'd missed something.  I know where the null reference is (`r` is null in `string result = r.ToString();`, (commented as line 217) but I can't see where that null comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A a check for null would be more prudent, because the due to the structure of the code, when a `catch` happens and `compiled` is null and it then runs code which *happens to* expect that `compiled` will not be null.

So

Change:

```
       catch (PythonParseException)
        {
            // not valid python, try next expression
            continue;
        }
        dynamic r = pythonEngine.Evaluate(compiled);
```

to

```
       catch (PythonParseException)
        {
            // not valid python, try next expression
            continue;
        }
       if (compiled != null)
       {
        dynamic r = pythonEngine.Evaluate(compiled);
        String result = r.ToString(); //  Action.cs: line 217, wrapped at  ActionTest.cs: line 96
        str = str.Replace(expression.Template, result);
       }
       else
       {
           str="Exception Caught";
       }
       break;
```